# trigger dom-level events

Tags: mootools

Does anyone know of a method to trigger a click on an element with mootools at the dom level?

`foo.fireEvent('click')` will, for instance, only fire events added *by mootools*, which is not very helpful for this particular application.

Here's a fiddle with a toy example - you can see that clicking the top button will fire off both event handler functions, while trying to use the lower button to trigger a click will only fire off the 2nd function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tc4Bv/

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Yikes - in my experience, it's been better to just bite the bullet and refactor your existing inline click handler to be added via mootools. As they say, it's looking a little [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: The problem is that I'm interfacing with a 3rd party, remote script that attaches and event to an element on the page through an unknown method.  If it was my code I was trying to trigger, it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modern browsers have an `Element.click` method available, so you could try something like this:

```
Element.implement({
    synteticClick: function() {
        var click = 'click';
        (this[click] && !(this[click]())) || this.dispatchEvent(new Event(click));
        return this;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/LUPYK/

works/tested in latest FF, Chrome, also IE9 and IE9 in IE7 mode (compat).

keep in mind that the event object may be basic, i.e. lacking clientX/Y etc - so it very much depends on what you do at the other side...

Comment: I was actually experimenting with that - it seems like the click method only exists on UI elements such as links and buttons; not images.

Comment: Ah - still experiencing some quirks, but this put me on the right track - thanks.